# Chartjs Legend Styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to to style style my Chartjs legend but for some reason it is not allowing me to override the font color. I want to change the font color to white while retaining the colors for each item in the bar chart, and then I want them to be displayed horizontally instead like this:
[image]

**index.html**

```
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChart" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .chart-legend  li span{
    color: red !important;
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    list-style-type: none !important;

}
```

**This is how it currently looks:**
[image]

Comment: The code you are showing doesn't actually appear to be trying to change the font color. Have you tried just adding a CSS style `color: #FFFFFF;` (or the equivalent `color: white;`) for your font?

Comment: .chart-legend  li span{
    color: red !important;
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    list-style-type: none !important;

}

Comment: Yes, I added that sorry I removed it before showing, and it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to style your `ul` to remove the bullet points (and set the color) and you need to make your `li` inline. This should do this for you

```
.chart-legend ul {
    list-style: none;
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

.chart-legend li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that if you have additional CSS that targets the same elements you might need more specificity or style resets.

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bseccq9v/