# Is there a way to hide/customize ChartJS' above legend?

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm using ChartJS in my project (more exactly ng2-charts for Angular 2 built on top of the original library).

I see there is an option:

**legend: false|true**

However I find particularly annoying tot to be able to **remove** the **upper legend** (which describes each line in the line chart for example). Below you can see what I mean:

[image]

I tried with

```
.chart-legend {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
```

taking inspiration from [Chartjs Legend Styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082809/chartjs-legend-styling)

but I think that applies to some other legend (bottom legend).
Is there a way to customize / hide the upper legend?

Also, **is there an option to change x/y-axes label orientation**? (e.g. display them vertically, rather than diagonal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When creating a chart, you can give it a set of chart options. One of the possible options is the [Legend Configuration](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration). To hide the legend, simply use an option like this:

```
options: {
    legend: { display: false }
}
```

Although I haven't used ng2-charts, looking through the [documentation](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) (specifically the charts example) it seems you can simply define a chart legend boolean like this:

```
public lineChartLegend:boolean = true;
```

And then add this value to the chart like this:

```
   <base-chart class="chart"
                   ...
                   [legend]="lineChartLegend"
                   [chartType]="lineChartType"
                   ...></base-chart>
```

Finally, the likely reason why Chartjs Legend Styling solution doesn't work is that it was designed for chart.js v1.x, while ng2-charts appears to work with chart.js v2.x, which is a major change to the previous version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: adding it to the options ([options] in ng2-charts)worked. thank you!